# Value only gets passed on to another class if I use it as a static variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using information from one class to pass to another but the information only gets passed on if I use it as a static variable. If I use it as an instance, I am not able to get the value. I don't understand why there is an issue if I want to grab information from an instance instead. Please advice. Thanks.

```
//Following works where I declare score as a static variable
public class DestroyByContact : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int score = 0;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {       
        score += 10;
    }
}

public class UIScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Text text;

    void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        text.text = "Score: " + DestroyByContact.score;
    }
}
```

---

```
//The following doesn't work where I call an instance of the class. I get a NullreferenceException.

public class DestroyByContact : MonoBehaviour {
        public int score = 0;

        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {       
            score += 10;
        }
    }

public class UIScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Text text;
    DestroyByContact destroyByContact;

    void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
        destroyByContact  = GetComponent<DestroyByContact>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        text.text = "Score: " + destroyByContact.score;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the NullReferenceException? It's not clear what's going on. Is `text` null? Is `destroyByContact` null? Is `Start` actually being called? What debugging have you performed?

Comment: The NullReferenceException is occuring at the UIScript Class under the Update method. Says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: But which bit? Is `text` null, or is `destroyByContact` null? Again, have you debugged this at all?

Comment: why don't you do the following and you will see a difference 
`DestroyByContact destroyByContact;` change this to 
 `DestroyByContact destroyByContact = new DestroyByContact (); without declaring it static. also I think you should read up on Instance vs Static and Scope in regards to `private, public, static,etc.... look up how to use and when to use the `new` key word

Comment: Are you sure GetComponent() works? Debugged it?

Comment: One more thing - are you calling Start() before Update()? Looks like both text and destroyByContact would be null if you called Update() before Start()

Comment: I removed my answer because of the confusion in regards to if Unity allows it or not.. all I can suggest is debugging the code a bit further and changing the order of when you are calling certain methods in regards to initializing objects to prevent the null reference exception